# How to stop Chrome cutting off CSS blur filter when transitioning transform

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm building a visual effect in CSS which applies a `filter: blur` to an element and animates children of this element. Some of these children are partially out of view, which causes rendering inconsistencies in Chrome while animating:

While a transition is active, the CSS filter is rendered differently than when the element is stationary. It seems to crop and then blur only the part of the element that is within the viewport while it is moving. This leads to an unwanted gradient where the element touches the edge of the window (example below).

I presume a new stacking context is created when animating a transform, similar to when applying a `transform3d` or `will-change: transform`. Applying such properties leads to the same effect, even when the element is static.

When nesting the element in another element and setting the transform on the parent and the blur on the child the problem goes away. But this is not a solution for me, because I will be animating multiple elements and then blurring the container to achieve the visual result I'm after.

I've created a codepen with a minimal test case: https://codepen.io/larixk/pen/jONRoXO Here there is a single element with a `filter: blur` which transitions on `:hover`.

```css
.blurred {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;

  filter: blur(5vh);

  transform: translateY(-80%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.blurred:hover {
  transform: translateY(-20%);
}
```

Expected result while transitioning: 
[image: Imgur]

Actual result while transitioning: [image: Actual]

Seen in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 and Chrome Canary Version 79.0.3930.0.

Problem does not occur in Firefox (70.0b11) or Safari (13.0.1).

Is there something broken in Chrome, or am I missing something?

Comment: Incidentally, this looks to me like a browser bug.  I _think_ that [this chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=607831) describes the same issue-- if not, you _may_ consider opening a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
.blurred {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 50vmin;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    filter: blur(5vh);
    transition: 1s;
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
}

.blurred:hover {
    top: 0px;
}
```

You could also use vw rather than px if you wanted it responsive.

Comment: No idea! CSS is buggy, you've just got to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: That could be a workaround. Although it could introduce quite a performance hit. I'll investigate. Thank you.

Comment: Fair.  I agree with @Larixk that _generally_ using `transform`/`translate` is a more performant option for animating items position on the page-- however there seems to be a lot of weirdness in particular around how browsers render filters, so this may just be one of those cases (in fact, it appears there may already be a [chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=607831) open for this issue from 2016).  Nice fix.